type narrowing in typescript based on enum in type
say for example I have this type in typescript:
enum NumberOrStringType {
    NUMBER,
    STRING,
}

type NumberOrString = {
    dataType: NumberOrStringType,
    data: string | number;
};

and later in the code:
const numOrString: NumberOrString = { dataType: NumberOrStringType.NUMBER, data: 10 };

if (numOrString.dataType === NumberOrStringType.NUMBER) {
    const num: number = numOrString.data;
    ... 
} else {
    const str: string = numOrString.data;
    ...
}

Unfortunately, I get errors saying that type string | number is not assignable to type number and type string | number is not assignable to type string.
I know I can just cast num and str by using as number and as string respectively, but is there a way to tell typescript to determine the type of data via the enum is has been assigned, or by narrowing the type by using an if statement?

• Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos or other issues except for the one you're asking about. You should be able to test it in an IDE. • Assuming my fixes for those other issues are correct, the solution here is to make NumberOrString a discriminated union type, not an object type where each property is an independent union. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what's missing?

You need to use a discriminated union: otherwise there is no way for Typescript to infer that when dataType is NumberOrStringType.NUMBER that data is always number, and vice versa for string.
type NumberOrString = {
    dataType: NumberOrStringType.NUMBER;
    data: number;
} | {
    dataType: NumberOrStringType.STRING;
    data: string;
}

Once you do that your code should work:
const numOrString = { dataType: NumberOrStringType.NUMBER, data: 10 } as NumberOrString;

if (numOrString.dataType === NumberOrStringType.NUMBER) {
    const num = numOrString.data; 
} else {
    const str = numOrString.data;
}

See playground example here.

@jcalz Ah, that was TS inferring the object as const, I've updated the code now. Thanks!
